Android Emulator plays BUSY tone during active call
I am using Android emulator version 34.1.10.0 to receive a simulated call from the Extended controls:

Then I pick up the call in the emulator. As soon as I pick up, there is a persistent BUSY tone being played by the virtual device.
I am trying to find out the source of the tone and why is it played. In some older versions of the emulator I didn't experience this behavior.
I have tried finding it by looking at the logs with adb logcat and also by passing in the -verbose flag when starting the emulator. I haven't found anything related to playing this busy tone in either of the logs.
I have looked at the frequencies of the tone with a frequency analyzer. These are 480Hz+620Hz with 500ms on/500ms off periods. Looking through the AOSP code, this tone is either TONE_SUP_BUSY or TONE_CDMA_NETWORK_BUSY. That is, if the sound is generated by the ToneGenerator.
How can I go about finding the source of this tone?
